# vim doesn't react to register access command `"` - how to fix it?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Whenever I type `"` in normal mode in vim it never appears - the editor (I tried both on Ubuntu 16.04 and macOS 10.13 with terminal vim as well as Spacemacs with evil) does not react - double quote does not appear in the command line, nor editor pastes anything when I use, e.g. `"+p`. I verified with `:reg` that I have all default registers and they are filled with data.

What can be the source of the problem and how to fix it?

I very often come with a case where `"0p` or `"*p` would fit perfectly and have to deal with them manually.

Comment: what do you mean by `doesn't react`? the vim editor hangs? or what? can you show your vimrc? do you have mapping defined with `"` ?

Comment: I have same error. I confirm that isn't related with TMUX or plugins. I tried change my vim version and it's not solved.

Comment: what does `:verbose map "?` say, have you tried starting your vim with `vim -u NONE` ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo `verbose` command is not recognized by vim, nor `map`. @Kent - by doesn't react I mean it just behaves as if I've never typed `"`, no hangs, everything works fine. It looks like the key isn't bound to anything, I've started working with vim recently and it's awesome, though this part (lack of this feature) is still quite vague.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I tried `:verbose map "` on macOS this time, and it returns `no mapping found`. Running `vim -u NONE` runs normal vim with the same problem as described in my question.

Comment: and " works in insert mode?

Comment: yes, I'm able to write quotes normally

Comment: My Vim doesn't give any feedback when I press `"` either, but it doesn't mean it doesn't work. Try `"gp` (assuming `g` register is blank), while I have no indication I pressed anything after `"` or `g`, I get `E353: Nothing in register g` after punching `p`. Also, `"` should consume the next key; if you do `"L`, you should be in operator pending mode, with no reaction yet; do you execute `L` (go to low end of screen)?

Answer (score 0):

*I use Linux, so this solution will work on Linux and FreeBSD (maybe MacOS)*.

For me worked adding `set showcmd` into `.vimrc` file. To do it, execute this command:

```bash
echo "set showcmd" >> ~/.vimrc
```